Know the Solution Configurations (Debug/Release) of the solution and the project name within a t4 template using C#
I would need to know if my solution is in Debug or Release in a t4 template file and the project name.
The simplest way would be to read the values from the csproj file but a different behavior happens if I carry out a "Debug T4 Template" or if I carry out a Rebuild of the solution.
I would like to have the same data that I get with the "Debug T4 Template" also with the Rebuild of the solution.
I used the following lines:
`
string DebugRelease = Host.ResolveAssemblyReference("$(Configuration)");

string ProjectName = Host.ResolveAssemblyReference("$(AssemblyName)");`

When I rebuild I get $(Configuration) and $(AssemblyName).
The same problem happens to me when I used the following line of code.
string NameProject = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.Host.ResolveAssemblyReference("$(TargetPath)"));
When I rebuild I get $(TargetPath).
To understand if I'm in Debug or Release I also tried the #If Debug option but that doesn't work either.
I also tried using Env.DTE but ran into problems that way too.
